# Problems creating a new project in Watson Studio

Tags: watson-studio

I want to create my first project in Watson Studio; however, I can not do it because when I click on the "Create" bottom I receive the following message "Unable to configure credentials for your project in the selected Cloud Object Storage instance". Does anyone know what this means?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to be IBM Cloud account Administrator or Owner if you are using shared account within your organization.

If you are not account Administrator, you should ask account administrator to enable storage delegation for cloud object storage service used for project so that non-administrator users under that account can create project using that Cloud Object storage service.

Please check this documentation link:-
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/getting-started/projects.html?audience=wdp
(See Requirements section).
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/console/wdp_admin_cos.html?audience=wdp

There are also chances that this may be a temporary issue caused by some intermediate problem for IBM Cloud IAM service as this project creation attempts to create credentials for the storage service(IBM Cloud Object storage) you select, so you as account owner may also run into this issue. In such case, please reach out to IBM Support.